# Turning a canvas element into an image object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, transformation

I have a primary canvas element which I perform drawing operations on using the context. I can successfully draw images, shapes, and also transform those objects using the context.

I now need my own textbox. I want to create another canvas, render the text to that canvas, then copy that data onto the primary canvas... the catch is I want to have it transformable, almost is if I was just calling the drawImage function.

There exists the `getImageData` and `putImageData` methods, but those do not work because it does not take into consideration the transformation.

I am looking for something like this...

```
var tempcanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = tempcanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(0,0,5,5);
```

then on my primary canvas which I already have, I would like to draw that as if it were an image object.

```
context = maincanvas.getContext('2d');
context.translate(50,50);
context.rotate(180);
context.drawImage(tempcanvas)
```

Comment: No way. Transformations are only applied to paths and shapes as well as texts. And obviously they aren't applicable to pixel manipulation methods such as `drawImage`.

Comment: I must have not described my problem well enough. I have it working now. Answer to post shortly. Basically I saved the context as an image and then drew the image.

Comment: And have you tried it? drawImage accepts as source image a canvas, and even its own canvas.

Comment: @hindmost, you're wrong, transformations have an effect on drawImage, whoch os not a pixel manipulation operation btw.

Comment: Note (just in case) that rotate() needs an angle in radians not degrees.